# Unicode escaped comments in Python

Tags: python, unicode, escaping, comments, lexical-analysis

I made a Java program that uses unicode escaped characters to break a multiline comment and hide some functionality.  The program below prints "Hello Cruel World".  I'm wondering if this is possible to do in Python (any version).  If it is not possible, how is this prevented in the language?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    print("Hello");

    /*
     * \u002A\u002F\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0074\u0028\u0022\u0043\u0072\u0075\u0065\u006C\u0022\u0029\u003B\u002F\u002A
     */
    print("World");
}

private static void print(String s){
    System.out.print(s + " ");
}
```

Note that the unicode is the escaped string `*/print("Cruel");/*`

My fruitless attempt so far...

```
test = False

#\u0023test = True

'''
\u0027\u0027\u0027
test = True 
\u0027\u0027\u0027
'''

print(test)
```

Comment: dont ever do this ... what a horrible thing

Comment: I agree.  I'm looking for edge cases in program analysis tools...

Comment: I dont think you can do that in python ... thankfully

Comment: If you're looking for corner cases in a program analysis in Python, I imagine your worst nightmare would be the "exec" functionnality. Following your idea, it is possible to get some obfuscated code executed. i.e. `exec("\u0074\u0065\u0073\u0074\u0020\u003d\u0020\u0054\u0072\u0075\u0065")`

Comment: @Cilyan yeah but you still could not put that in the comments (or inside triple quoted string)

Comment: Not unless you process it: http://pastebin.com/itugy8FQ But you did not really defined which assumptions you make on what is possible what is not :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python lexer only processes Unicode escapes **within** Unicode string literals (`u''` in Python 2, `''` in Python 3), thus such an approach is not possible.

If you try just the simple space, `\u0020`, python spits out:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

That is because outside string literals, the `\` character is chiefly used in for breaking a long line into several shorter:

```
spam = foo + bar + baz + ham + \
       eggs + ham + spam + spam + \
       spam + sausages + spam
```

Outside strings, the only allowed character after `\` is a newline.